# How many arguments does a MATLAB function take?

Tags: matlab, function

Is there a way to find out how many arguments a function will take?

like this?

```
f = @(x,y,z) x+y+z;
numargs( f )

ans = 
      3
```

I know many functions take `varargin`, so maybe that would return `inf` or something.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [nargin](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nargin.html) to get the number of input arguments.

As for when a function takes `varargin` as input argument, the output of `nargin` will be negative.

Example from the docs:

```
function mynewplot(x,y,varargin)
   figure
   plot(x,y,varargin{:})
   title('My New Plot')
```

Calling `nargin` like so:

```
fx = 'mynewplot';
nargin(fx)
```

yields a result of -3, hence the 3rd input argument is `varargin`.

Comment: Cool!  Didn't know about that negative bit!

Comment: Ah I didn't realise it had a dual function - I have used it before only within a function to get the number of passed arguments.